# VisualStudio 2012 github integration

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, github-for-windows

I start to use VisualStudio 2012 and Github, unfortunatelly I do not know why I cannot commit changes. Picture shows the problem:

[image]

why I cannot commit&&push changes ? What should I do ?

**EDIT** With help console I can commit, but in VS I have following errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the picture, it looks as if you simply need to stage your changes (i.e. add them to the index) prior to trying to commit. To do this in Git Gui, you either click on the icons to the left of the files under "Unstaged Changes", or you select "Stage to commit" from the Commit menu, as per this tutorial:

http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_gui_windows.html

In case this is an issue of unfamiliarity with the way git itself works, you may want to read up on how git works with regard to its index/staging area - the book "Version Control with Git" (by Loeliger) is a good'n in this regard.

Comment: Can I staged files via VS ?

Comment: @MrPhi: Yes, there are Git plugins for Visual Studio itself, e.g. see http://agile.dzone.com/articles/git-visual-studio-and-net.

Comment: Thank you very much, I code in Eclipse and I do not know VS environment..thanks ! !